# Busybox SUID on NFS rootfs

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, boot, nfs, rootfs

I am building a Linux system from the bottom for a Beagle Bone board. I have compiled the vanilla kernel and built a basic root file system with `busybox`. The system is booted with U-boot, while the `rootfs` is located on a Linux PC and exported through NFS:

```
/path/to/rootfs  10.42.0.17(rw,wdelay,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

The U-boot `bootargs` are:

```
bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=${serverip}:/path/to/rootfs,v3,tcp ip=dhcp
```

I've encountered a problem when trying to get `su` working for non-root users. In order to work around the problem people over internet are suggesting to set the `suid` bit for the `busybox` binary. 
After doing so:

```
$ sudo chmod u+s busybox
```

and verifying:

```
$ ls -la
...
-rwsr-xr-x  1 myuser myuser 1882976 Jan 13 21:47 busybox
...

$ stat -c "%a %n" busybox 
4755 busybox
```

Something went wrong. The kernel is booting and all of the usual messages are displayed, but it is getting stuck at the end, and no `login` line is displayed. Here are last few lines of the booting sequence:

```
[    3.776185] IP-Config: Complete:
[    3.779656]      device=eth0, hwaddr=c8:a0:30:c5:80:e9, ipaddr=10.42.0.17, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=10.42.0.1
[    3.789877]      host=10.42.0.17, domain=, nis-domain=(none)
[    3.795822]      bootserver=10.42.0.1, rootserver=10.42.0.1, rootpath=
[    3.802492]      nameserver0=10.42.0.1
[    3.871575] VFS: Mounted root (nfs filesystem) on device 0:15.
[    3.879903] devtmpfs: mounted
[    3.883713] Freeing unused kernel memory: 380K (c07ef000 - c084e000)
```

If removing the flag, the things are returning to normal:

```
....
[    3.862291] Freeing unused kernel memory: 380K (c07ef000 - c084e000)

10.42.0.17 login:
```

If setting the flag from within the running shell on the Beagle Bone board itself, the shell is stopping responding right after the `chmod` is performed.
 I suspect it is something to do with the way the NFS is exporting the rootfs, but it's only a guess, so qualified explanation and possible solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I will answer my question myself. The answer is very simple. In order the above to work, the `busybox` binary should be owned by `root:root`. The simplest solution is just to change the ownership.